# How do I print my outputs into the form of a table?

Tags: c, printing

This is what my output should look like:

[image]

Since it's a little hard to read, essentially, it's this diagram, we're basically just substituting the values we get for the function into the boxes:

[image]

NOTE: That the first box is NOT (1, 1), it is (1, 20).

I wrote some code for this but the output isn't in that table form, and I'm not sure how to get it into something that looks like that. And we have to do this for multiple functions but just so that it's easier for you to look at/work with, I'll just post up two of the functions that I have to do.

Here are the two functions:

[image]

And here's my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "grove.h"

int main() {
   int i, j;
   double soilqual, sunexp, irrexp, yield, qual, harvtime, plantcost, ppu,
      rev, fprofit, retinvest, annurev, fscore;

   printf("================ Soil Quality ================\n");
   for (j = 20; j >= 1; j--) {
      for (i = 1; i <= 20; i++) {
         soilqual = soilQuality(i, j);
         printf(".3%f\n", soilqual);
      }
      printf("\n");
   }
   printf("---------------------------------------------------------------            -----\n");
   printf("\n");
   printf("================ Sun Exposure ================\n");
   for (j = 20; j >= 1; j--) {
      for (i = 1; i <= 20; i++) {
         sunexp = sunExposure(i, j);
         printf(".3%f\n", sunexp);
      }
      printf("\n");
   }
   printf("---------------------------------------------------------------            -----\n");
   printf("\n");
}
```

Comment: Do you really want your table as badly laid out as it looks?  Wouldn't it be better to use a format like `%8.3f` to make the columns uniform for the given data?  You also don't want the newline in the innermost format strings.  The `%8.3f` format will leave a blank at the start of a 2-digit value (and also a blank for the sign if the value is positive, or a minus sign if it is negative).  So, you probably won't need to add extra spacing to the array for the shown data.  You might prefer to include the space anyway; it ensures that the numbers won't run into each, no matter how large they are.

Comment: Thanks for your input! But yes, I need it to look exactly like the table that I posted above. :)

Comment: Yuck; a format for computers and not for humans, then.  But even dumb computer programs usually manage to skip extraneous space.  However, so be it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure I got what you want, but if you are trying to have a grid that has 20 column and 20 row try substituting the \n in the printf in the inner loop with a space:

```
  printf("================ Soil Quality ================\n");
   for (j = 20; j >= 1; j--) {
      for (i = 1; i <= 20; i++) {
         soilqual = soilQuality(i, j);
         printf(".3%f ", soilqual); <<-- here
      }
      printf("\n");
   }
```